# Does making document inside a document in firebase increases max size to 2mb?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i wanted to ask if i make a initial collection (collection>document1>collection>document2),
my question is will the document2 size be 1mb as well as the size of document1 = 1mb? total of 2mb
or just 1mb for the entire document and sub collections and document dont count ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

A document is stand-alone. The maximum 1MB quota on a document does not include documents in subcollections.

The above explains why we could have some "posts" subcollection in a "users" documents (let's say we are in a social media app). The posts by a given user would grow so much you know. You don't expect Firebase to prevent more creation of posts for the 1MB reason. I hope this further explains the answer.

It is worth mentioning that querying in Firestore is shallow. In other words, fetching a document doesn't recursively fetch all the other documents in subcollections.

Know more about Firestore Quotas here at https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas

Comment: so will fetching a document inside another document count as 2 document reads and ill be charged for 2 documents read?

Comment: no it is one document read. It will count as 1. Let's say you are using `firestore.doc('collection1/doc1/collection2/doc2').get()` , you are just using the `get` method on a single doc to return just one document. In fact see it that every time the `.get` method is called on a `.doc` (and it successfully returns, then it is just one read. Irrespective of the document path.

Comment: just last question so  as documetn is stand alone if ii have document2 inside a document1 then both the documents are stand alone? meaning no matter of the sub collections both the documts will have there own 1mb data size

Comment: yes yes, now you understand it well.